# vite loading file no longer referenced

Tags: vite, sveltekit

I tried to share code between firebase functions and my src/lib directory in a svelte kit project, which didn't work out. But after I've removed everything I can think of, the browser console still tries to load the /functions/src/shared/defs.ts file (which obviously doesn't work).

I run 'npm run dev' and it still tries. It's 'stuck' in there somewhere, but I can't grep where. I want to 'npm run clean' or something. I tried deleting everything in ./svelte-kit/generated and ./svelte-kit/output but that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Vite has its own [cache](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#file-system-cache).

> If for some reason you want to force Vite to re-bundle deps, you can either start the dev server with the `--force` command line option, or manually delete the `node_modules/.vite` cache directory.

Local files should not end up in there, I think, though.

I always have the browser dev tools open to also disable the browser cache, there usually is checkbox for that in a network related tab.

Other than that, it probably would have to a stray reference somewhere.